# PHP time localisation server to region

Tags: php, timezone

On my server database I have a **datetime** attribute with server time and my data is like this:

```
2015-08-05 18:50:00
```

On my compter time is:

```
2015-08-05 21:50:00
```

How can I convert the server time from server database to local time per different users for different regions? For example, I need to add 3 hours for my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for timezones. [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) make this easy.

```
$datetime = new DateTime(); // now in server time zone
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); // change TZ to New York (ET)
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You just need to change the timezone to be the one that applies to your scenario. There is a [list of timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) to choose from.

If you want to be sure the starting timezone is consistent just in case your server timezone changes you can explicitly declare that, too.

```
$datetime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); 
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/412750)

Comment: So I need to get user's timezone programmatically?

Comment: Yes. And [here's a nifty way to do it.](https://trevoro.net/2013/whats-your-timezone/)

Comment: I can't see the link, guess about your privacy settings on pocket

Comment: Oops. Fixed the link to go to the original article.